# Update json field in postgres table

Tags: python, sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to add even more key : value data to existing json data. I get data from postgres with a query to the field and get a dictionary. After that, I simply add an additional key-value pair to the dictionary as follows:

```
conn=Connection()
a=conn.get_user_data(user_id)[0][0]
a['new']='data'
```

I get an updated dictionary with all the necessary fields:

```
a={'index': True, 'old':'data' , 'new':'data'}
```

After I try to populate the column with new data like this:

```
a = str(a)
a = a.replace("'",'"')
query = '''UPDATE table SET data = ('{}') '''.format(a)
conn.cursor.execute(query)
conn.connection.commit()
```

I am getting the following error:

> psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for
> type json LINE 1: UPDATE table SET data = ('{"inde... ^ DETAIL: Token
> "True" is invalid. CONTEXT: JSON data, line 1: {"index": True...

Is there any other way to update json field in postgresql or how can i fix my way given that 'index' contains BOOL True in db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not manipulate the json as a string in your Python script.

Also, use the parameter binding capabilities to avoid SQL injection.

```
import json

a={'index': True, 'old':'data' , 'new':'data'}
query = '''UPDATE table SET data = %s '''
conn.cursor.execute(query, (json.dumps(a), ))
conn.commit()
```

Do you need a `where` clause in your SQL?  You know that this will update all  rows in the table, right?